# Magento 2 Customer and Order Migration Mismatch of entities in the document: sales_order_grid

Tags: magento2, customer, sales-order, data-migration

I've migrated the customers&Orders from Magento 1.9.0.1 Version to Magento 2.2.6 Version so that I have implemented migration-tool. in in my config.xml, I have the following code

config.xml

```
<config xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xs:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../config.xsd">
 <steps mode="settings">

</steps>
<steps mode="data">
    <step title="Data Integrity Step">
        <integrity>Migration\Step\DataIntegrity\Integrity</integrity>
    </step>

    <step title="Customer Attributes Step">
        <integrity>Migration\Step\Customer\Integrity</integrity>
        <data>Migration\Step\Customer\Data</data>
        <volume>Migration\Step\Customer\Volume</volume>
    </step>
    <step title="Map Step">
        <integrity>Migration\Step\Map\Integrity</integrity>
        <data>Migration\Step\Map\Data</data>
        <volume>Migration\Step\Map\Volume</volume>
    </step>

    <step title="OrderGrids Step">
        <integrity>Migration\Step\OrderGrids\Integrity</integrity>
        <data>Migration\Step\OrderGrids\Data</data>
        <volume>Migration\Step\OrderGrids\Volume</volume>
    </step>

    <step title="SalesIncrement Step">
        <integrity>Migration\Step\SalesIncrement\Integrity</integrity>
        <data>Migration\Step\SalesIncrement\Data</data>
        <volume>Migration\Step\SalesIncrement\Volume</volume>
    </step>

</steps>
<steps mode="delta">
    <step title="Customer Attributes Step">
        <delta>Migration\Step\Customer\Delta</delta>
        <volume>Migration\Step\Customer\Volume</volume>
    </step>
    <step title="Map Step">
        <delta>Migration\Step\Map\Delta</delta>
        <volume>Migration\Step\Map\Volume</volume>
    </step>
    <step title="OrderGrids Step">
        <delta>Migration\Step\OrderGrids\Delta</delta>
        <volume>Migration\Step\OrderGrids\Volume</volume>
    </step>
    <step title="SalesIncrement Step">
        <delta>Migration\Step\SalesIncrement\Delta</delta>
        <volume>Migration\Step\SalesIncrement\Volume</volume>
    </step>
</steps>
<source>
    <database host="localhost" name="m1901-php56" user="root" />
</source>
<destination>
    <database host="localhost" name="magento226-migration2" user="root" />
</destination>
<options>
    <map_file>etc/opensource-to-opensource/1.9.0.1/map.xml.dist</map_file>
    <eav_map_file>etc/opensource-to-opensource/map-eav.xml.dist</eav_map_file>
    <eav_document_groups_file>etc/opensource-to-opensource/eav-document-groups.xml.dist</eav_document_groups_file>
    <eav_attribute_groups_file>etc/opensource-to-opensource/eav-attribute-groups.xml.dist</eav_attribute_groups_file>
    <log_map_file>etc/opensource-to-opensource/map-log.xml.dist</log_map_file>
    <log_document_groups_file>etc/opensource-to-opensource/log-document-groups.xml.dist</log_document_groups_file>
    <settings_map_file>etc/opensource-to-opensource/settings.xml.dist</settings_map_file>
    <customer_map_file>etc/opensource-to-opensource/map-customer.xml.dist</customer_map_file>
    <customer_document_groups_file>etc/opensource-to-opensource/customer-document-groups.xml.dist</customer_document_groups_file>
    <customer_attribute_groups_file>etc/opensource-to-opensource/customer-attribute-groups.xml.dist</customer_attribute_groups_file>
    <delta_document_groups_file>etc/opensource-to-opensource/deltalog.xml.dist</delta_document_groups_file>
    <order_grids_document_groups_file>etc/opensource-to-opensource/order-grids-document-groups.xml.dist</order_grids_document_groups_file>
    <map_document_groups>etc/opensource-to-opensource/map-document-groups.xml.dist</map_document_groups>
    <class_map>etc/opensource-to-opensource/class-map.xml.dist</class_map>
    <tier_price_map_file>etc/opensource-to-opensource/map-tier-price.xml.dist</tier_price_map_file>
    <stores_map_file>etc/opensource-to-opensource/map-stores.xml.dist</stores_map_file>
    <!--
    In case bulk_size=0 it will be auto-detected for every document.
    -->
    <bulk_size>0</bulk_size>
    <!--
    Set direct_document_copy = 1 for better performance.
    NOTE: 'source' and 'destination' databases MUST be placed on the same MySQL instance
    and 'destination' user MUST be granted with 'SELECT' permissions on 'source' database
     -->
    <direct_document_copy>0</direct_document_copy>
    <source_prefix />
    <dest_prefix />
    <auto_resolve_urlrewrite_duplicates>0</auto_resolve_urlrewrite_duplicates>
    <log_file>migration.log</log_file>
    <progress_bar_format>%percent%% [%bar%] Remaining Time: %remaining%</progress_bar_format>
    <upgrade_customer_password_hash>1</upgrade_customer_password_hash>
    <edition_migrate>opensource-to-opensource</edition_migrate>
    <edition_number>1.9.0.1</edition_number>
    <init_statements_source>SET NAMES utf8;</init_statements_source>
    <init_statements_destination>SET NAMES utf8;</init_statements_destination>
    <crypt_key>5e93e93d3903732369e0bf5bddaa8d2e</crypt_key>
</options>
```

then I run the following command for migration

```
php bin/magento migrate:data -a vendor/magento/data-migration-tool/etc/opensource-to-opensource/1.9.0.1/config.xml
```

but while i check in customer_entity and sales_order table there is no records.
Kindly share your idea and thoughts, thanks in advance for your support

for your further reference, Herewith I've updated the success screen

[image]

Comment: Is there any error ?

Comment: I think you missed crypt key in config.xml

Comment: I don't have crypt key, I check with the Magento 1.9.0.1 pack in app/ect/local.xml, in there is no tag <key>. how can I get the crypt key

Comment: In every Magento 1.9.0.1 Installed version crypt key is the same one or else it'll vary for each installation?

Comment: I have 6 magento install on my local, all having key and all are different

Comment: I have included my crypt key inside the option tag <crypt_key>5e93e93d3903732369e0bf5bddaa8d2e</crypt_key>, then run the mirgrate data command, it's showing migration completed, but still there is no recoreds in customer and order table

Comment: Have you been able to solve this problemo?

Comment: how to did u fix this error? can u guide me  https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/284577/magento-2-customers-data-migration-volume-check-failed

Comment: Old question but still an up-to-date topic since many might face this problem oftenly. In case you want a quick solution and don't mind spending small budget, come visit our migration tool and see how it can migrate any type of entity respectively extremely accurate.

Answer (score 0):

It happened to me something like this!
I solved like this:
https://github.com/magento/data-migration-tool/issues/467#issuecomment-627912182

Hope it can helps someone!