# Magento 2 customer data migration & volume check failed?

Tags: magento2, customer, customer-address, data-migration

I would like to migrate only customers data using magento2 data migration tool. 
Can anyone suggest how to resolve the below error when migrating data

```
[2019-08-06 12:20:19][INFO][mode: data][stage: volume check][step: Map Step]: started
100% [============================] Remaining Time: < 1 sec
[2019-08-06 12:20:23][WARNING]: Mismatch of entities in the document: customer_address_entity Source: 15 Destination: 0
[2019-08-06 12:20:23][WARNING]: Mismatch of entities in the document: customer_address_entity_int Source: 15 Destination: 0
[2019-08-06 12:20:23][WARNING]: Mismatch of entities in the document: customer_address_entity_text Source: 15 Destination: 0
[2019-08-06 12:20:23][WARNING]: Mismatch of entities in the document: customer_address_entity_varchar Source: 106 Destination: 0
[2019-08-06 12:20:23][WARNING]: Mismatch of entities in the document: customer_entity Source: 26 Destination: 0
[2019-08-06 12:20:23][WARNING]: Mismatch of entities in the document: customer_entity_datetime Source: 1 Destination: 0
[2019-08-06 12:20:23][WARNING]: Mismatch of entities in the document: customer_entity_int Source: 74 Destination: 0
[2019-08-06 12:20:23][WARNING]: Mismatch of entities in the document: customer_entity_varchar Source: 141 Destination: 0
[2019-08-06 12:20:23][WARNING]: Volume Check failed
```

Map step is responsible for mapping most of the data is either copied (or) transformed from M1 to M2 like a catalog, customer, email templates, catalog media gallery data ..etc.

If enabled map steps customers data not migrated properly & if disabled email templates are not migrated properly.

```
 <step title="Map Step">
        <integrity>Migration\Step\Map\Integrity</integrity>
        <data>Migration\Step\Map\Data</data>
        <volume>Migration\Step\Map\Volume</volume>
    </step>
```

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/164989/magento-2-is-it-possible-to-migrate-only-customer-using-migration-tool?noredirect=1#comment407683_164989

Comment: I think the issue is with the customer with the IDs in the source. May be duplicate customer emails are present in the database. Please cross check it in the M1 database.

Comment: did u face this issue earlier when you migrated from m1 to m2?

Comment: can u please help me on this https://codeshare.io/2jb6kL

Comment: Yes, I've faced these kinds of issues while migration. Also, for the commands, it is better to use the command with -r (reset) parameter instead of a (auto) data migration.