# How to migrate email templates only from M1 to Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, email-templates, data-migration, data-migration-tool

We have installed migration tool in Magento 2.3.1 EE (composer require Magento/data-migration-tool:2.3.1 ) would like to migrate M1 commerce edition (1.14.3.1) to Magento 2.3.1 EE.

We have migrated customers & orders & products data but we would like to migrate email templates can anyone guide me how to do it step by step?

Is it possible to migrate email templates using the data migration tool?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I've completely migrated data from Magento 1 to Magento 2 (orders, products, customer, rules, coupons, newsletter subscribers etc) and yes email and newsletter templates can be migrated with the data migration tool.

Comment: can we migrate only email templates? I observed that email templates were migrated at Map step am I correct?

Comment: In this case, We can migrate them directly from the database tables.

Comment: can you please advise how to do it?

Comment: Sumit  i am doing some R&D on data migration can u please review and help me on this ? https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/284577/magento-2-customer-data-migration-volume-check-failed

Comment: Check the database table columns of Magento 1 and 2, you can directly import M1 email templates data to M2 email templates table.

Comment: hi @sumit actually I have a task on data migration from M1 to M2 customers, orders, Mirasvit RMA data, email templates only without touching product data. can u please advise?

Comment: For this, instead of migrating them one by one you can migrate all the Magento data and after successful migration you can remove the product data from the database.